# Android XML how to set 5 image button vertical and horizontal fit all screen size

Tags: android

All people help me , how to set 5 image button vertical and horizontal fit all screen size ?
[This Screenshot Image Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRDbZ.png)

[Link complete xml code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_PX3b-UgC8lNDBKTlZNT1BCSGc/view?usp=sharing)

I have a code like the following, but the image appears small button on the screen 5 inches and above :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mode2"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:tag="2"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mode0"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mode2"
        android:background="@drawable/button2"
        android:tag="0"
        android:translationY="-75dp"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mode4"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mode2"
        android:background="@drawable/button3"
        android:tag="4"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mode1"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/mode0"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mode2"
        android:background="@drawable/button4"
        android:tag="1"
        android:translationY="75dp"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mode3"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mode4"
        android:background="@drawable/button5"
        android:tag="3"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best you could do is to use a LinearLayout  and the images will auto audjust within the screen bounds. Like this.Example of Horizontal.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="5"
android:orientation="horizontal"    //Or Vertical
>

<ImageButton 
android:id="@+id/ib1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/image"/>

<ImageButton 
android:id="@+id/ib2"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/image"/>

<ImageButton 
 android:id="@+id/ib3"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:weight="1"
 android:background="@drawable/image"/>

<ImageButton 
 android:id="@+id/ib4"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/image"/>
<ImageButton 
 android:id="@+id/ib5"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for comment, I've updated the xml code and picture detail, please see again : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_PX3b-UgC8lNDBKTlZNT1BCSGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The picture you uploaded i think you did not use different density images . right ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp">

    <Space/>

    <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/button2"/>

    <Space/>

    <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/button1"/>

    <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/button5"/>

    <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/button3"/>

    <Space/>

    <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/button4"/>

    <Space/>

</GridLayout>
```

You also need to create button images for different dpi folders to fit different screens

Comment: thanks for comment, I've updated the xml code and picture detail, please see again : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_PX3b-UgC8lNDBKTlZNT1BCSGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't think you have even read anyone's answer. My code could solve the horizontal problem. To solve the vertical problem, like ljl5241861 said you need to calculate the button size in JAVA code based on screenwith and then set the button height.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table layout within relative layout, change the gravity to center

Answer (score 0):

you need dynamic layout in your activity, when activity start you need to get the screen width and height,then calculate your width and height you need in proportion and then set layoutparams to your imageView,others you need multiple size.

Comment: thanks for comment, I've updated the xml code and picture detail, please see again : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_PX3b-UgC8lNDBKTlZNT1BCSGc/view?usp=sharing